I want to detect Device Current font in flutter. Is there any way to use because there is no libraries related to this
I am creating a app in flutter where i want to use system fonts.In native android or iOS we do not need any extra code for this bu in flutter there is no way found.
I am trying Platform channels to use this feature but this also doen't help here is my platform code
//iOS
private func getSystemFonts() -> [String] {
           let fontFamilies = UIFont.familyNames
           return fontFamilies
       }

// Android
private fun getSystemFonts(): List<String> {
        val fonts = mutableListOf<String>()
        val typefaceClass = Typeface::class.java
        val fields: Array<Field> = typefaceClass.declaredFields
        for (field in fields) {
            if (field.type == Typeface::class.java) {
                fonts.add(field.name)
            }
        }
        return fonts
    }


